# Bind delphi SOAP client to a specific local port/range

Tags: delphi, networking, soap, port

I am consuming a web service with Delphi SOAP library (using THTTPRIO). One of the customers has strict networking policy requiring specific ports to be used on both sides of connection. So I need the web service client to use a specific local port or small local port range to make the connections to the server. Is there a way to do it (either through programming or using a Windows setting)? I am using Delphi 10.4.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I get the question right, but I think it would be as simple as specifying a port number as part of the URL property of a THTTPRIO object as below.

```
// Example of AUrl: 'http://COMPNAMEORIPADD:9878'
function SoapClientClass.CreateSoapClient(AUrl: string; AInterfaceName: string): THTTPRIO;
begin
  result := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  result.URL := AUrl + AInterfaceName;
end;
```

Comment: That would be for the server port, wouldn't it? The client will open connection from some private port (eg. from 49,152 through 65,535 on Windows) on local PC to server COMPNAMEORIPADD:9878. However I need to restrict the range of private ports the client is using on the local PC, so it uses eg. only private port 50120 or some port between 50120-50130 to create the connection on local PC.

Comment: Sorry @Johnz, I think I have misunderstood your question. I thought it was for binding the server port.